# Sending ASCII byte streams to a pipe

Tags: c, shell, ascii, echo

I have a pipe created at /tmp/mypipe in a C program. The pipe is used to send and receive command bytes over two modules in the program. A module sends data as specified in the below structure:

```
struct controller
{
  int command;
  char data[100];
}
```

I want to send data to /tmp/mypipe in the same format. I tried the below command and the C program receives the data.

```
echo -e "\x00\x00\x00\x04"www.google.com > /tmp/mypipe
```

But, the data that is received by the program is in the below format:

```
control.command = 67108864
control.data = www.google.com
```

What I want is that control.command to be received as mere number 4. I tried multiple suggestions that I found via google. But, when I try to redirect the data to a pipe, it fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely using a little endian machine, thus you should present the number in little endian

```
echo -e "\x04\x00\x00\x00"www.google.com > /tmp/mypipe
```

or, preferably, choose an endianness in the contract of your interface and make sure you convert it to the machine's endianness in your code

```
NAME
htonl, htons, ntohl, ntohs - convert values between host and network byte order  

SYNOPSIS
#include <netinet/in.h>

uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);

uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);

uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);

uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);
```

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The htonl() function converts the unsigned integer
>   hostlong from host byte order to network byte order.
>
> The htons() function converts the unsigned short integer hostshort
>   from host byte order to network byte order.
>
> The ntohl() function converts the unsigned integer netlong from
>   network byte order to host byte order.
>
> The ntohs() function converts the unsigned short integer netshort from
>   network byte order to host byte order.
>
> On the i80x86 the host byte order is Least Significant Byte first,
>   whereas the network byte order, as used on the Internet, is Most
>   Significant Byte first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Big/Little endian issue.

On your system you should use:

```
echo -e "\x04\x00\x00\x00"www.google.com > /tmp/mypipe
```